# Why the following C code is not outputting the execution time in Raspberry Pi Pico W board using Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-c++, raspberry-pi-pico

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void setup() {

  struct timeval start_time;
  struct timeval end_time;

  gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);

  //code here

  gettimeofday(&end_time, NULL);

  long int elapsed_time=0;

  elapsed_time= (end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (end_time.tv_usec - start_time.tv_usec);

  printf("Elapsed time in microseconds: %ld\n", elapsed_time);
}

void loop() {

}
```

I need the execution time of C/C++ program by running it in Raspberry Pi Pico board. I am using Arduino IDE 2.0.3 and Raspberry pi pico w 2022 board. The output shows like the following.

```
Elapsed time in microseconds: 0
Elapsed time in seconds: 0.000000
```

Comment: Are you actually running something between the measurements?

Comment: You may also want to handle the `tv_usec` case where end microseconds are less than start. E.g say start happens at `900000` usec (`.9` sec) and end occurs at `100000` usec (`.1` sec). Why not simply use the pico API such as `get_absolute_time()` and then `absolute_time_diff_us()`? See [Pico-Time timestamp](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__timestamp.html)

Comment: For my studies , I need to find the time taken by a Raspberry pi pico board to sort an array of 10000 numbers. I need that execution time only. I have to run the same algorithm (Quick sort) on various languages like C/C++,micropython on Raspberry Pi. I got the time for micropython. But failed to get the execution time in C/C++ in arduino IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You should try "pico/time.h".